# Running JMeter from apachejmeter.jar - Giving an error in the Jmeter Script execution, Works when run with jmeter.bat file

Tags: java, jmeter, jmeter-5.0

I have a simple JMeter script , where I am using parallel controller to send few GET requests.
When I am running the script ,by loading the JMeter using jmeter.bat file. The Jmeter Test works without any error.
When I am running JMeter from ApacheJmetr.jar file from the bin , I am getting the below error
So I wanted to know what exactly is the difference as it is working from jmeter.bat file and not from apachejmeter.jar file.

````
java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make field java.lang.ThreadLocal$ThreadLocalMap java.lang.Thread.inheritableThreadLocals accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.lang" to unnamed module @222114ba
    at java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:354) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:297) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.reflect.Field.checkCanSetAccessible(Field.java:180) ~[?:?]```
````

Answer (score 0):

[`jmeter.bat`](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/rel/v5.5/bin/jmeter.bat) startup script is a wrapper which generates some parameters for the Java Virtual Machine, in particular your error is due to missing parameterse which are set in [line 112](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/rel/v5.5/bin/jmeter.bat#L112)  (for [JMeter 5.5](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-5-5))

So you either need to:

1. Downgrade your Java to [Java 8](https://openjdk.org/projects/jdk8/)
2. Or to add the same JVM arguments as `jmeter.bat` startup script does, to wit:

   ```
   java --add-opens java.desktop/sun.awt=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.desktop/sun.swing=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.desktop/javax.swing.text.html=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.desktop/java.awt=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.desktop/java.awt.font=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.lang.invoke=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.lang.reflect=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.text=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.desktop/sun.awt.shell=ALL-UNNAMED -jar ApacheJMeter.jar
   ```